# How to plot decay curve in R?

Tags: r

I tried code from the web to plot a decay curve but I never got a graph with the point and at the same time the decay curve. What I got instead was a scatter-plot with points joined by line. Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

I did use **ggplot2: geom_point and geom_smooth, geom_line and other options**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
    "d weighted_LD
     1.400   0.00002198
     1.450   0.00001849
     1.500   0.00001652
     1.550   0.00001673
     1.600   0.00001067
     1.650   0.00001647
     1.700   0.00001861
     1.750   0.00001903
     1.800   0.00001949
     1.850   0.00001966
     1.900   0.00001781
     1.950   0.00001327
     2.000   0.00000964
     2.050   0.00001383
     2.100   0.00000492
     2.150   0.00001325
     2.200   0.00001706
     2.250   0.00002061
     2.300   0.00002108
     2.350   0.00001343
     2.400   0.00001627
     2.450   0.00001545
     2.500   0.00000920", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by decay curve.

If this is about fitting a general exponential model of the form `y = beta0 * exp( beta1 * x)`, a good starting point would be to `log`-linearise your data and fit a linear model:

```
fit <- lm(log(weighted_LD) ~ d, data = df);
fit;
#Call:
#lm(formula = log(weighted_LD) ~ d, data = df)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            d
#   -10.5438      -0.2864

df$pred.y <- exp(predict(fit));

ggplot(df, aes(d, weighted_LD)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(aes(d, pred.y), colour = "red", size = 1) +
    labs(x = "d (cM)", y = "Weighted LD")
```

[image]

Using `stat_function` with the `fit` parameters produces the same plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(d, weighted_LD)) +
    geom_line() +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) exp(coef(fit)[1] + coef(fit)[2] * x), colour = "red") + 
    labs(x = "d (cM)", y = "Weighted LD")
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = 
    "d weighted_LD
     1.400   0.00002198
     1.450   0.00001849
     1.500   0.00001652
     1.550   0.00001673
     1.600   0.00001067
     1.650   0.00001647
     1.700   0.00001861
     1.750   0.00001903
     1.800   0.00001949
     1.850   0.00001966
     1.900   0.00001781
     1.950   0.00001327
     2.000   0.00000964
     2.050   0.00001383
     2.100   0.00000492
     2.150   0.00001325
     2.200   0.00001706
     2.250   0.00002061
     2.300   0.00002108
     2.350   0.00001343
     2.400   0.00001627
     2.450   0.00001545
     2.500   0.00000920", header = T)
```

Comment: Using a linear model to smooth an exponential decay is probably not the right thing here:  it fits the model `y = A + B * exp(-x)`, rather than the more usual `y = A * exp(-B*x)`.  The former has an asymptote at `A`, not at `0` as you'd expect with a decay curve.

Comment: @user2554330 It's not clear to me at all if this question is about *fitting a model*, or about how to plot data. OP needs to clarify. Generally I agree with you, but "decay curve" is a mathematically pretty ambiguous term.

Comment: Fair enough.  A really useful improvement to your answer would be to plot the data and a curve specified in a function (maybe found by `nls()`, maybe otherwise) on the same plot.  I know how to do that in base graphics, but not in `ggplot2`.

Comment: @user2554330 My feeling is that `nls` would be overkill, even more so in view of OP's rather diffuse question; I imagine that a simple `log`-linearised model would be a good starting point. I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to do `geom_function` :-(.  It's bad when limitations of software determine the statistical analysis.

Comment: @user2554330 There is no `geom_function`. But you can define a custom function within `stat_function` and plot that together with the data. It gives the same plot. See my update.

Comment: @user2554330 One more comment on `nls`: If you wanted to avoid linearising your data, in this case I would strongly advise against `nls` and instead use a `glm` with a `log` link. Results will be identical, and GLMs are a lot more stable than using non-linear fitting. So in this case, this would be something like `glm(weighted_LD ~ d, data = df, family = quasi(link="log", variance="constant"))`.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answers even my question was not clear enough. My point is to plot the decay curve in plus of the scatterplot like this

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answers even my question was not clear enough. My point is to plot the decay curve in plus of the scatterplot like this http://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/193/4/1233/F4.large.jpg . I have some negative values so I got NaNs values which are inducing errors when trying to use the Maurits Evers first suggestion about fitting the data. I hope the link will help better. Thank you

Comment: @RindraRakotoarivony You need to provide details about the functional form of the model you want to fit. I just had a quick look at the image you link to, and this doesn't look like an exponential decay. The paper may provide details. This question is turning into something more of a work project, which is off-topic here on SO. I would suggest you either [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49956088/edit) the original question to provide a **reproducible and answerable problem statement including sample data**; or close the question by setting the check mark next to the answer.